# Strange behaviour of DocumentFragment.innerHTML on different websites

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument

Could you help me with understanding why this happens?

Follow these steps to reproduce the behaviour:

1) Go to any youtube's video page, for example [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0)

2) Wait till complete loading of the page and then go to console and copy the whole html as string (`document.documentElement.outerHTML`)

3) Then execute the next code on youtube and on any another website(for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/)). (`COPIED_MARKDOWN` is step 2)

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var tmp = fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("div") );
tmp.innerHTML = COPIED_MARKDOWN;
var target = tmp.querySelector('#page-manager')
console.log(target)
```

The result:

1) When you execute the above code on youtube, you will see a tree of html nodes, but `<ytd-page-manager id="page-manager" class="style-scope ytd-app">` won't have any children. (screenshot № 1)

2) When you execute the above code on another website, you will see a tree of html nodes, and `<ytd-page-manager id="page-manager" class="style-scope ytd-app">` will have children (screenshot № 2)

Also you can download my small chrome extension and load it on both websites to skip steps above

Extension: https://ufile.io/uy3pg

Screen № 1: http://joxi.ru/YmEzvLOH0dwV82

Screen № 2: http://joxi.ru/D2Pzv1qHpQqykr

**I tested it only on chrome: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: Probably there's code on youtube.com that handles [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) like `<ytd-page-manager>`

Comment: @Bergi I tried to delete all scripts tag from COPIED_MARKDOWN but the result is still the same. DocumentFragment is isolated from the real document and there should be no conflict. I don't know where to dig more

Comment: I'm pretty sure the custom element registry applies to markup in document fragments as well - it's not like you're creating an entire new document, you are still in the tab where the scripts originally took effect.